# Pointer address of a struct

Tags: go

Consider this code :

```golang
package main

import "fmt"

type S struct {
    Val  int
}

func main() {
    e1 := S{Val: 1}
    fmt.Printf("%p\n", &e1)
    fmt.Printf("%p\n", &e1.Val)
}
```

After running it, we'll get something like that:

```
0xc00001c030
0xc00001c030
```

What confuses me is why pointer's address of the struct and it's member are the same?

Link to Go Playground: https://go.dev/play/p/Wl4tnD9TFmA

Comment: I believe that is only true for the first member.

Comment: The address of the first field is the same as the struct's address, there's nothing surprising in it. If you have more fields, their addresses won't be the same.

Comment: Flip the question: why do you expect it would be different? What did you expect the address of the field to be, and why?

Comment: @Adrian for some reason I thought that the struct itself could contain some meta-information connected to it which has its own address, but now it's obvious that it isn't.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Struct is memory area with all fields put there one by one (if alignment present, then they could be with gaps). Same as array. So first element of struct obviously should have same address as struct itself.